# What kind of DataStructures can enable parallel processing

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, algorithm, parallel-processing

Binary Tree:
For example, if we need to process Tree datastructure parallely. We can spawn one thread to process left node, and another thread to process right node. Now both can independently run on the same data strucuture.

It is certainly not possible to have same kind of parallelism for linked list.

I am thinking, if there are any other data structures, that gives us the flexibility for acheiving parallelism similar to a binary tree ?

Comment: What's wrong with traversing to the middle of a linked list, and spawning two threads to work on their elements in parallel? If your "processing" is sufficiently complex, it may be a win.

Comment: Just chop the linked list into pieces. Trivial concern in terms of parallelism. If something else was writing to your tree while you were processing, the fact it was conveniently split left and right isn't going to help is it?

Comment: Depends what you mean by “processing”: most common operations on a binary tree (searching, inserting, deleting … ignoring the rebalancing) cannot be meaningfully parallelised due to the divide&conquer nature of the binary tree.

Comment: Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504906.aspx

Answer (score 3):

What type of parallelism? You can always read in parallel but for writes it's more complicated. If the only thing that is being changed is the data stored in the node there is no reason why you can't parallelize a `LinkedList` or an `Array` by creating a lock for each individual node rather than the entire list. But if the connections of the structure is affected then there are more things to worry about.

The answer depends on what you are trying to do and how you set up the locks, conditions etc but nothing is inherently parallelizable or uparallelizable.

Answer (score 0):

When you talk about parallel processing two things come in my mind 1) Task Parallelism 2) Data Parallelism. I will talk about the second here.

Check superset of Trees: Graphs. Many huge data problems based on Wisdom of Crowd/Collective Intelligence can be modelled as a Graph. Parallel processing of Graph using Map Reduce framework will be interesting for you to go through.